# Is there a term for numbers with the same tens digit?

Tags: word-request, numbers

I want to know if there's a certain term or a way to call numbers with the same tens digit as a group, just like we call someone whose age is between 20 to 29 "in his/her 20s".

For example, if I'm playing bingo and I want to say something like, "Does anyone have a number between 30 and 39?" Is there any other way to say it?

Answer (score 2):

"Does anyone have a number in the thirties" works well for many groups. For 10-19 you might say "in the teens" (but this might be understood as 13-19) and "below ten" for 0-9.

It's harder to say "having the same tens digit". You could say "I'm grouping the numbers by their tens digit" then "These numbers are in the same group". Where "group" is understood in context.

Comment: This answer is correct. English does not have an **un-ambiguous** term for the group 10 through 19.